# How to customize the UIPickerView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uipickerview

I am working with UIPickerview. I want to make my view as:

[image: View as needed]

But I am getting as:

[image: View as I am getting].

Is there a way to bring the selectionIndicator close to the string? And to hide numbers that will come above the selectionIndicator?

Comment: I think There is no way to do like this. Pickerview is default provided by functionality and you cant make it custom. So use as it is

Comment: Check my answer.it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

lakhan bhojwan try below answer.I created sample one.It works perfectly.

ViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController<UIPickerViewDelegate,UIPickerViewDataSource>

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIPickerView *pickerCustom;

@end
```

ViewController.m

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()
{
   NSMutableArray *arrPicker;
}

@end

@implementation ViewController

@synthesize pickerCustom;


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
  [super viewDidLoad];
  // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
   arrPicker = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"Rate this page",@"10",@"9",@"8",@"7",@"6",@"5",@"4",@"3",@"2",@"1",nil];       
   [pickerCustom selectRow:1 inComponent:0 animated:YES];   
}


- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
   [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
   // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


// The number of columns of data
- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
{
   return 1;
}

// The number of rows of data
- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
   return [arrPicker count];
}

// The data to return for the row and component (column) that's being passed in
- (NSString*)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
   return arrPicker[row];
}

@end
```

Below output screenshot

[image]

Comment: Here you are just providing with the basic pickerview. I want the selectionIndicator close to the string "rate this page"

Comment: rate this page is label or picker view data?

Comment: Clearly it would be a label